# angular 6 hashin the end of url

Tags: angular, typescript

i used `hash` in my router, when i navigate for example in `FrameworkModule`, the url shows like this 
 `http://localhost:4024/#/framework#`, It adds hash in the end of the url, when i refresh the pages the url becomes like this `http://localhost:4024/#/framework%23`, the hash in the end changes to `%23` and it redirect to `NotFoundComponent`

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "Accueil" } },
      { path: 'framework', loadChildren: '@framework/framework.module#FrameworkModule', data: { title: "" } }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  providers: [ { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Framework Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListFrameworkComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FrameworkRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: `%23` is the Hex representation of `#`, so this should not be a problem, it should get received as `#` when you resubmit. Is that not the case?

Comment: Can you clarify if this causes some types of failures or downstream problems for your app? Or is it just how the browser shows it?

Comment: @joanis when the  url shows like this `http://localhost:4024/#/framework%23` it redirect to `NotFoundComponent`

Comment: I suggest you add that right in your question, it's critical information to help someone answer. (I don't know how to help you here myself, sorry.)

Comment: What happens  when you use following url: http://localhost:4024/framework and http://localhost:4024/framework#